# How to iterate thorugh JSON/dict in python3?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, python-requests

I'm sending request to an API using python's `requests` module and the response is in JSON (can be called dictionary right?)

If I do

```
for i in response:
    print(i)
```

It would only print the key (the parameter) and not the value, how to get both as output. Thanks.

Comment: JSON can be *decoded* into a `dict` (or a `list`, or a `str`, or an `int`, etc). Until you decode it, JSON is just a *string*. Given your description, you have already decoded the JSON, so the fact that your `dict` came from a JSON value is no longer relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `items` to loop over the key/value pairs at the same time.

```
for key,value in response.items():
    print(key, value)
```

The [`items`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) method returns an iterator over the key/value pairs of a dictionary.

Comment: i did the exact same thing without `iteritems` what is it?

Comment: @Jam `iter(response)` (which is how the `for` loop gets an iterator from the iterable you use) returns an iterator over just the keys of the `dict`.

Comment: Yes, it worked but can anyone please exaplain what is `items` here?

Comment: [As documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), `items()` returns an iterable whose iterator yields tuples of keys and their associated values.

Comment: `iteritems()` was what it was called in Python 2.